# Creating new elements with xmlstarlet

Tags: command-line, command, xml, xmlstarlet

I have been trying to to add new elements to an XML file.

Original file:

```
<levela>
  <levelb>
  </levelb>
</levela>
```

I'm trying to get the following result:

```
<levela>
  <levelb>
    <levelc>
      <element1>value1</element1>
      <element2>value2</element2>
      <element3>value3</element3>
    </levelc>
  </levelb>
</levela>
```

My current attempt is:

```
xmlstarlet ed -a /levela/lelvelb -t elem -n levelc -v "" \
    -i //levelc -t elem -n "element1" -v "value1" \
    file.xml
```

But my file isn't updated.

Answer (score 3):

There’s a typo in your `xmlstarlet` invocation (`lelvelb`):

```
xmlstarlet ed -a /levela/lelvelb -t elem -n levelc -v "" \
    -i //levelc -t elem -n "element1" -v "value1" \
    file.xml
```

To add a subnode, you need to use the `-s` operation, not `-a` or `-i`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -s /levela/levelb -t elem -n levelc -v "" \
    -s //levelc -t elem -n "element1" -v "value1" \
    file.xml
```

This produces

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<levela>
  <levelb>
  <levelc><element1>value1</element1><element2>value2</element2></levelc></levelb>
</levela>
```

You can add other `-s` operations as necessary. You can also drop the empty `-v` for `levelc`.

If you want to modify `file.xml` itself, instead of getting the result of the transformation on `xmlstarlet`’s standard output, add the `-L` option to `ed`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -s /levela/levelb -t elem -n levelc -v "" \
    -s //levelc -t elem -n "element1" -v "value1" \
    file.xml
```

Comment: Ah yes, thanks @muru!

Comment: This is a brilliant question and answer. Thank you.